# ASP.NET Core How Can I Convert Uploaded Files To Pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I made this ASP.NET project in which I delimitated the roles of the users and admins, for example the admins can also upload files while the users can only download them. Thing is, I need to have every word document that is uploaded converted into pdf, so that whenever the user wants to preview he will preview the pdf, and whenever he wants to download, he will download the .docx version. I have no idea how to do that, can anybody help me?
'''

```
   List<AdminModel> adminModels = new List<AdminModel>();
    interface Iuser
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        void IsEqualTo();
    }
    class User : Iuser
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        

        public void IsEqualTo()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class Admin : Iuser
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public void IsEqualTo()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Index1()
    {
        // Get files from the server
        var model = new FilesViewModel();
        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
        {
            model.Files.Add(
                new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
    {
        // Iterate each files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Get the file name from the browser
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            // Get file path to be uploaded
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);

            // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
            using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

        // Get files from the server
        var model = new FilesViewModel();
        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
        {
            model.Files.Add(
                new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null)
            return Content("filename is not availble");

        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
    private string GetContentType(string path)
    {
        var types = GetMimeTypes();
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
        return types[ext];
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {".txt", "text/plain"},
            {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
            {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
            {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
            {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
            {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {".png", "image/png"},
            {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
            {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
            {".gif", "image/gif"},
            {".csv", "text/csv"}
        };
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }'''

    [HttpGet("denied")]
    public IActionResult Denied()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    public IActionResult Secured()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnURL"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Validate(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
    {

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        List<Iuser> utilizatori = new List<Iuser>();
        utilizatori.Add(new User() { username = "username", password = "password" });
        utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "bobitza", password = "28" });
        utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "rares", password = "cretin" });

        foreach (Iuser user in utilizatori)
        {
            if(user.username==username && user.password==password)
            {
                if (user is User)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>();
                    claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                } 
                else if (user is Admin)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>();
                    claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                }    
                
            }
        }
        
        

        
          
        TempData["Error"] = "Error. Username or Password is invlaid";
        return View("login");
    }
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Word can export a document as a pdf, anything else will not give you an equivalent file.

Comment: @jeremy: except that you shouldn't run Word on a server (I used to know the KB article # about that by heart). You are going to want to find a server-capable product to do that. Don't do the work within an ASP.NET app pool, run the conversion in a separate process. Rendering PDFs in a .NET process will very likely blow out the Large Object Heap and cause you process to spend all it's machine cycle on the GC thread

Comment: Hmmm, seems like microsoft have an online preview thingy, https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/. Not sure how you could use it for an arbitrary document

Comment: Found the "Office Web Viewer"; https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/ but the info seems outdated.

Comment: Hmmm, this looks interesting; https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ / https://devscopeninjas.azurewebsites.net/2017/04/07/preview-documents-stored-in-sql-using-office-web-apps/

Comment: your upload-action could execute e.g. libreoffice (headless, :/# /path/to/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /tmp/whatever /path/to/test.docx ) or any other docx2pdf tool on the server side using System.Diagnostics.Process after the upload

Comment: If it is an option for you, you could consider a document toolkit like the LEADTOOLS SDK (Disclaimer:  I work for the vendor) has a [.NET Core Document Converter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/dotnet-core-convert-files-with-the-document-converter.html) that can be used on the Server side to create the PDF version of the uploaded document.